# How fastly read non contiguous rows from cloud Bigtable from non-google-cloud data center

Tags: google-cloud-bigtable, bigtable

I have a table exists in Bigtable (BT) with huge data. I have a REST API. During that API execution, I query BT and process the results and send back to client. I was trying to read huge amount of data from BT, but the response time was not good.

To read 30K records from BT, it took more than 50 seconds time for first time. The successive calls took 10-30 seconds. What are the best ways to improve read latency in java?

I tried below two approaches, but no luck.

**Approach 1:**
I used [google-cloud-bigtable](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/reading-data) dependency to read data from BT from my java API.

I used `newBulkReadRowsBatcher` to send keys in batches. I set the batch settings like below

```
    Long setElementCountThreshold = 15L;
    long setRequestByteThreshold = 60L * 1024L;
    Long setMaxOutstandingElementCount = 3000L;
    BatchingSettings batchingSettings = BatchingSettings.newBuilder() .setElementCountThreshold(setElementCountThreshold) .setRequestByteThreshold(setRequestByteThreshold) .setDelayThreshold(Duration.ofSeconds(1))//.build(); .setFlowControlSettings(FlowControlSettings.newBuilder(). setMaxOutstandingElementCount(setMaxOutstandingElementCount).build()).build();
```

**Approach 2:**
I used [java Bigtable hbase API](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/hbase-bigtable) to connect to Bigtable and read from it. Here also I did not get proper response times when I tried to read huge data.

```
Result[] rows = table.get(queryRowList);
for (Result row : rows) {
}
```

I used both the approaches by splitting row key list into subsets and wrote the logic to read the data using multiple threads by sending each subset in a thread. But did not see any improvement in the response.

- I did not find how to do batch processing and do bulk reads here using this client. I found Async bulk read logic [here](https://github.com/googleapis/java-bigtable-hbase/pull/1217/files) but did not get that library with the below dependency.

```
implementation 'com.google.cloud.bigtable:bigtable-hbase-2.x:2.6.5'
```

BTW my table schema is like below

```
row key : 48characters
this row key is divided into 3 qualifiers in the column family
one more qualifier which holds json string as a value (which I am interested in to use in the API)
```

Can anyone please suggest any ways that I implement to improve read performance with either of the above approaches?

Comment: Please check these documentations on [schema design best practices](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/schema-design) and [performance](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/performance) in order to get the best performance. Hope the links above would be helpful.

Comment: I have checked these links already. My schema is under best practices. It has one column family with row key which is combination of 3strings(around 45chars) and other column(which holds json string). My data in the table is under the [limits](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/quotas#limits-data-size).
Checking the ways to retrieve data at fast speeds.